# How can I use multiple IP cores that both contain modules with the same names with Yosys

Tags: yosys

Consider a design with two IP cores `ip1.v` and `ip2.v` that each declare a (different) module with the same name.

For example, the contents of `ip1.v`:

```
module ip1 (input A, B, C, output X);
  wire T;
  mygate gate_0 (.I0(A), .I1(B), .O(T));
  mygate gate_1 (.I0(T), .I1(C), .O(X));
endmodule

module mygate (input I0, I1, output O);
  assign O = I0 & I1;
endmodule
```

And the contents of `ip2.v`:

```
module ip2 (input A, B, C, output X);
  wire T;
  mygate gate_0 (.I0(A), .I1(B), .O(T));
  mygate gate_1 (.I0(T), .I1(C), .O(X));
endmodule

module mygate (input I0, I1, output O);
  assign O = I0 | I1;
endmodule
```

And then a top module that uses both IP cores (`top.v`):

```
module top (input A, B, C, output X, Y);
  ip1 ip1_inst (.A(A), .B(B), .C(C), .X(X));
  ip2 ip2_inst (.A(A), .B(B), .C(C), .X(Y));
endmodule
```

How can I process a design like that so that each IP cores sees it's own version of `mygate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For situations like this it is necessary to read and elaborate the two IP cores as separate designs and then link it all together by "importing" the two designs for the individual IP cores into the top-level design:

```
# Read IP core 1
read_verilog ip1.v
hierarchy -top ip1
design -stash ip1

# Read IP core 2
read_verilog ip2.v
hierarchy -top ip2
design -stash ip2

# Read top level and link design
read_verilog top.v
design -import ip1
design -import ip2
synth -top top
```

The command `design -import ip1` will import the modules `ip1` and `mygate` from the `ip1` design, but it will rename `mygate` into `ip1.mygate`. Similarly `design -import ip1` will rename `mygate` from `ip2` to `ip2.mygate`.